# SharePoint:DateTimeControl DatePickerImage javascript

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, datepicker

I need to get `DatePickerImage` control of  `SharePoint:DateTimeControl`.
I tried :

```
document.getElementById('<%=DateDebut.Controls[0].ClientID %>')
document.getElementById('<%=DateDebut.Controls[1].ClientID %>')
```

and it gives me only date information.

Any idea how I can get this control?

Comment: is there a solution to make SharePoint:DateTimeControl readonly and to disable the DatePickerImage with javascript

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to use:

```
document.getElementById('<%=DateDebut.Controls[0].ClientID %>+"DatePickerImage"');
```